# When joomla will get bootstrap 3?

Tags: joomla-3.4, bootstrap

Is there any time-line when joomla start supporting bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Migrating from Bootstrap 2.x to 3.x will take a very long time.

I think it's being considered, but doubt very much this will be in Joomla 4.x, therefore I assume it will be introduced in Joomla 5.x.

#### Update:

<strike>Just asked one of the PLT members and Bootstrap 3 won't be used. Bootstrap 4 is currently in alpha so by the time Joomla 4 is released, Bootstrap 4 will be stable and possible shipped with Joomla. They're also looking at non-Bootstrap frameworks just in case.</strike>

#### Update 2:

Joomla 4 **WILL** ship with Bootstrap 4.

#### Update 3:

Joomla 4 eventually shipped with Bootstrap 5.

Comment: "They're also looking at non-Bootstrap frameworks just in case" --> UIKit maybe? :D

Comment: @webchun - I will love Joomla forever if they choose UIKit :)

Comment: Haha, I personally LOVE UIKit, but I somehow doubt they'll go with something that's not as widely used as Bootstrap. But yeah, I'd actually love it too if they use UIKit. :)

Comment: There is a UX team for Joomla. Volunteers are welcome so I might actually join and put the UIKit idea forward.

Comment: oh my! J4 is just about to come out and be the standard version and it was discussed in 2015 that BS4 would be used with J4. I don't know whether I should be concerned with this pace or actually love it, because it's not as crazy fast paced as everything else these days... anyways, back to work.